# Getting 403 response error code when using Google Books API

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-403, google-books-api

So I'm using [Google Books API](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#request) and my code looks as follow:

```
 axios
  .get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" +
      this.props.categoryName +
      "&key=myKey"
  )
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

On using this API, I'm getting the following error:

[image: request failure error]

I did a bit of research online and it's saying that we get this error when we make way too many requests from a given API key but I have made only 5 till now and still it's throwing this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
The default limit is 1,000 per day.
```

More info - https://www.codementor.io/@srvkataria/how-i-bypassed-google-books-api-rate-limits-or-quota-vpmra29q0

Comment: But I have made less than 1000 request at the moment, so why it's still throwing the error